# good examples of model-view-controller

Tags: iphone

I'm new to Objective-C and the iPhone and thought I was getting the hang of it until, after many play apps, I ran into a really basic problem around MVCs, NIBs and IB. Are there any really clear explained examples of how to follow this framework that I could go back to?

```
@interface test1ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet myView *myview;
    IBOutlet myModel *mymodel;
}
```

Both the views and models are linked in by IBOutlets but instantiating the model object either kills the application or produces an object which does not respond to any messages.

I am also unclear as to where to carry best out initialisations. I currently do this over viewDidLoad in the view controller. Is there a standard way to do this and does the simulator actually always start up in the same way? Should one use awakeFromNib? Does it make any difference if I use plain code or the IB? And if I have use the IB, should it include a model object?

The MVC idea would make good sense for me here because I have potentially several views and view controllers all feeding back into - and sharing - one common central data model. Any references or advance on this newbie problem would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IB makes functionality invisible. I don't like it and I don't use IB any more, preferring to have everything in code. Then when you look at code you see what is going on - all the navigation controllers, all the formatters etc. - without switching over to IB. Maybe Xcode4 will make it better with integrated IB but I probably won't go back. Lots of people do like IB so try both methods and see what you like best.

IBOutlet/IBAction actually mean nothing to the compiler but they let IB recognise the ivars  it can send messages to or that will write to elements in a xib. Your use of it here is a bit simplistic unless you really do have a model that only communicates one way with the xib. What you more usually have is a range of controls in the xib linked to the view object, the view communicating directly with the controller. The controller communicates with the model. Very loosely speaking, model is your internal representation of data and logic, view is what you see, controller is the glue between them.

The MVC line can be fuzzy and you just have to get comfortable with it. If you have a slider control with a value representing some value in your model then it can be hard to think of it as part of the interface especially when you persist the value and use it as a central part of your model. I like the Stanford iPhone class introduction of it. They don't spend a heap of time on it because it can be difficult to follow exactly and there are situations where it isn't best.

[Notes from that class](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/131) - you can find the video on iTunes to follow along.

Your use of viewDidLoad is correct, that's your chance to perform initialization on views and their objects. If using IB you will probably not have much to do there because you can set most properties in the xib. If not using IB you will use it a lot more.

Comment: Don't Fear The Interface Builder http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/dont-fear-interface-builder.html

Comment: When it becomes part of Xcode proper, perhaps. Switching to IB is clumsy. And I've had too many cases of "connected" properties where they required disconnection and reconnection to actually be so.

Comment: This is very useful although I guess I'm going to take some time to get to grips with it all. The 2010 Fall iOS course looks very useful as to date I've only been looking at the 2009 iPhone programming one and youTube.

Comment: I say IB makes functionality more obvious.  Rather than view code scattered all over creating objects, setting frames and so on, you have one place where you can view the layering, can right click on the files owner and see all the connections.  I use IB exactly because it's MORE obvious how everything in a view relates, not less.

Comment: Just looked at the 2010 course. Really like this; is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about the 'classic' definition of MVC. iOS follows it, but there's a lot of confusing terminology. ("View Controller")

You say trying to use model kills your app.  Are you retaining myModel?  You have to retain all IBOutlets.

nibs are collections of "Freeze-Dried" objects.  When you load a nib, the objects in it are "rehydrated", if you will.  This means they spring back to life with all of their properties set to whatever they were when you froze them.  So you talk of "instantiating" and "initializing" but this does not apply to IB.  The objects are ALREADY instantiated and initialized.  Imagine that compiling the nib 'pauses' the objects.  When you load the nib, the objects resume doing whatever they were doing when frozen.  They will get an awakeFromNib message, so that's a good place to put some code to check on what the state of the app is, see if you have to do stuff with your object to bring it up to speed.

viewDidLoad seems like an "initialization" method but don't be fooled.  It's part of the view controller life cycle and it can be called more than once! (If your controller's view is purged as part of a low memory warning, viewDidLoad might be called again if the view has to be... wait for it... reloaded.)  So, it's appropriate to put view setup stuff in viewDidLoad, but not other initialization type things.

For the "common data" thing, I like to create a singleton data model class.  Your various views can set properties on the model, or send notifications.  You can also use KVO (key value observing) to watch for changes in the model.

Comment: Many thanks for your help on this. The freeze-drying certainly makes sense and I take heed of the viewDidLoad warning especially for data. Will also follow up KVO. From what you say, and also from what seems to happen with my code, first and second runs of an app must be different. I suspect there is no easy way of cleaning out a NIB for debugging etc? Did not realise that its written in XML.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times something like your model would be wired at runtime by your application delegate or by the view controller itself.

IB is generally used more to link views and controllers together, with the application handing around model(s).

That said, you should be able to have IB create an instance of your model and assign it in an IBOutlet.  Was your model OK with just being created without the classic init method being called?  Did it implement NSCoding properly?

Comment: I tried that but may have forgotten to take the init out. Will certainly follow this up but will first make sure I really have this IB thing in my head. You may be right though as it was the init method that seemed to be causing part of the problems. Did not implement NSCoding.

Comment: Since IB is creating objects, and relies on NSCoding to save them - that's why it might have an issue there.  That's also why there are proxy objects in IB, that are meant to represent a real object at runtime and are passed to IB through a userinfo dictionary when you are asking to load a nib.  That might be easier or make more sense for you than implementing NSCoding, but you'd have to figure out where to initialize the model.  And if you've done that, you can just give it to the controller directly...